# MSI to uninstall before new install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, windows-installer, uninstallation

I want to reinstall over an existing installation. is it possilble to configure MSI to automatically  uninstall the existing (whatever version) and then install the 'new' version.I would like to be able to uninstall before the install and I can't seem to find out how. Any/all help would be greatly appreciated.

I have done all these steps below and still feel that the product is not getting uninstalled but instead the files are getting overwritten.

1. Set Remove Previous Installation as True
2. Set Detect new version as True
3. You should change version of your installer to one higher version
   and it will ask you to change product code, select YES. Do not
   change your upgrade code, let it be same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you want a [Major Upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `RemoveExistingProducts` action scheduled before the `InstallInitialize` action. That will cause the old package to be removed before the new one starts to install (you'll still go through the new MSI UI).

Comment: How do i know (test) if it did the uninstall before i did the install?

Comment: A verbose log file will show you the uninstall of the old package before installing the new one.

Comment: Let me thank you first for all the help.
In the logs i see: "MSI (s) (88:A0) [16:26:31:058]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {F82F9400-36D3-D3F8-E550-5071B2FE587D} since another client exists" i think it is not uninstalling and just overwriting it.. What do you think?

Comment: VSI is limited in its configuration choices. You need to get the `RemoveExistingProducts` action set before `InstallInitialize` and that is not what it does. A tool like the `WiX toolset` can do all those things.

Comment: Hello Rob.. Did not know you were THE ROB of WiX.. But glad to know you are helping me.. I had one doubt.. What if someone cancels before InstallInitialize, will there be an issue? What is the license for wix if one wants to use commercially?

Comment: Cancels before InstallInitialize - nothing happens, UI just closes. Cancels after InstallInitialize but before new install hits InstallFinalize - you end up with nothing on the machine. The license on the WiX toolset does not affect output see: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2012/8/20/the-wix-toolset-license

Comment: Can we get a syntax example on this?